# i use Google place Api but when use near search place like bank & restaurant & .. this not work?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-api

1.i enable android google map android api and google places Api for android

2.my google map is worked but when use Search place thats Not Work

this my code please help me

```
manifest:
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="6" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my API_KEY" />
```

> google place avtivity :

```
public class GooglePlacesActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY   = "my api key";
GoogleMap                   googleMap;
EditText                    placeText;
double                      latitude         = 0;
double                      longitude        = 0;
private int                 PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 5000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
    if ( !isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_places);

    placeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.placeText);
    Button btnFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
    SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    googleMap = fragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

    btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String type = placeText.getText().toString();
            StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + "hospital");
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY);

            GooglePlacesReadTask googlePlacesReadTask = new GooglePlacesReadTask();
            Object[] toPass = new Object[2];
            toPass[0] = googleMap;
            toPass[1] = googlePlacesUrl.toString();
            googlePlacesReadTask.execute(toPass);
        }
    });
}


private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}


public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
}


public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}
i cant find nearshearch place :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

<

```
meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR API KEY"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

instead of

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="6" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my API_KEY" />
```

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/selecting-google-place-from-autocompletetextview-and-marking-in-google-map-android-api-v2/    use this

Comment: this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/selecting-google-place-from-autocompletetextview-and-marking-in-google-map-android-api-v2/ is useful  .................. thank u Mr Verma